# export a report as a CSV with custom object

Tags: apex, lightning, class

I want to export report with custom object  that when name of report equal to field custom name report  on custom object but i want that user can view all list in just select what report is want to export.

i start to write code in apex class

```
lobal class Exporter implements System.Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        DoExport();
    }
    
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void DoExport(){
        List<Exporter__c> exportList = new List<Exporter__c>{};
        List<Report> exportsf=new List<Report>{};
        List<Exporter__c> exportUpdateList = new List<Exporter__c>{};
        List<Report> exportupdatesf=new List<Report>{};
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails  = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Datetime dt = DateTime.newInstance(Date.today(), Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));
        Date d = Date.today();
        Date firstDate = d.toStartOfMonth();
        Date lastDay = firstDate.addDays(Date.daysInMonth(d.year(), d.month())-1);
        
        system.debug('First Day: ' + firstDate);
        system.debug('Last Day: ' + lastDay);
            
        exportList = [Select Id, Name, Report_ID__c, Attachment_Name__c, Email_Subject__c, Email_Body__c, Email_Recipients__c, Frequency__c, Weekly_Days__c, Monthly_Day__c, Last_Ran__c, reportname__c  from Exporter__c];
        exportsf=[Select Id,name from Report];
        for(Exporter__c e : exportList){
        for(Report r:exportsf)
        {
       
        
            //Determine if Exporter record is scheduled to run today.
            Boolean process = Test.isRunningTest() ? true : false;
            Boolean process_sf= Test.isRunningTest() ? true : false;
             
            //Test for Weekly frequency.
            process = e.Frequency__c == 'Weekly' && e.Weekly_Days__c.contains(dt.format('EEEE')) ? true : process;
            
                    //Test for Monthly frequency.
                    process = e.Frequency__c == 'Monthly' &&  (e.Monthly_Day__c == String.valueOf(d.day()) || e.Monthly_Day__c == 'last' && d == lastDay || lastDay.day() <= Integer.valueOf(e.Monthly_Day__c)) ? true : process;
                    process_sf=e.reportname__c==r.name ? true : process_sf;
 
                       
            //Run process if scheduled.
            if(process&&process_sf){
        
                System.debug('Starting message processing for: ' + e.Name);
        
               ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/' + r.id+ '?csv=1');
                ApexPages.PageReference objPage = new ApexPages.PageReference(url);
                Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
                attachment.setFileName(e.Attachment_Name__c);
                Blob content = Test.isRunningTest() ? Blob.valueOf('UNIT.TEST') : objPage.getContent();
                attachment.setBody(content);
                attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {attachment});
                message.setSubject(e.Email_Subject__c);
                message.setPlainTextBody(e.Email_Body__c);
                String[] emailRecipients = e.Email_Recipients__c.split(',');
                message.setToAddresses(emailRecipients);
                mails.add(message);
                System.debug('Completed message processing for: ' + e.Name);
                
                //Update Last Ran date and add to update list.
                e.Last_Ran__c = System.now();
                exportUpdateList.add(e);
                exportupdatesf.add(r);
                
            }
        }
        //Send the email messages all at once to avoid limits.
        Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
        System.debug('Send emails.');
        
        //Update Export record with Last Ran date.
        update exportUpdateList;
        
    }
}
}
```

This is my error:

```
First error: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
```

also my Code Coverage is 42%

please i need help with that anybody have a solution about that?

or another question how i can save a report name from standard object to reportname__c custom field on custom object(lookup)? because i want that i can with report name export report replace used with id of report.

please i need help with that.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Please keep each post to _one_ distinct question (see [ask]). You can open more than one post for separate issues. Note that both "Uncommitted work pending" and code coverage issues are well-covered in our knowledge base - search SFSE for hundreds of examples.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, the reason is you're doing callout after the DML. Imagine a sequence - Callout + DML + callout is happening in your case.

DML -         `update exportUpdateList;`

And as per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getContent.htm), `objPage.getContent();` is getting treated as the callout.

> If you use getContent in a test method, the test method fails. getContent is treated as a callout in API version 34.0 and later.

As a solution, **please take the update operation out of the for loop** and try to update there.